# javascript testing if a value is a number AND a number greater than 0

Tags: javascript

I have an object property that may or may not contain a number and that number may or may not be equal to `0`. For the moment, I have this:

```
var TheVar = parseInt(SomeObject.SomeVar, 10);

if (!TheVar > 0) {
   TheVar = "-";
}
```

I want `TheVar` to be either a positive number or `"-"`. I'm just wondering if my conditional statement is going to cover every case?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: What will you accept as a number? If it can be successfully coerced into a number, and not result in `NaN`, will you accept it? Or do you require something that is already a `number` primitive value?

Comment: ...you're not responding for some reason, so I'll give you some examples that are not primitive numbers, but will be successfully coerced into a positive number by the `>` operator. A numeric string... `"  123  "`, number in an Array... `[123]`,  numeric string in an Array... `["  123  "]`, hexadecimal string... `"0x15"`, hexadecimal string in an Array... `["0x15"]`, positive boolean... `true`, a Number object wrapper... `new Number(123)`. There are perhaps others that I'm not thinking of as well.

Comment: @amnotiam: sry, I was having dinner. I got it, thanks for your input, upvoted your comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. You are missing parentheses.

```
if( !(TheVar > 0))
```

`NaN > 0` returns false, so the `if` condition will go through.

Comment: It would actually have resulted in `boolean > 0`, where `boolean` is the result of the `!` operator since `!` has a higher precedence than `>`. ...but the solution is correct. :)

Comment: ...oh, maybe I misunderstood your `NaN > 0` statement. I get what you're saying now. Only question is if OP wants coercion, which is taking place here. `[123] > 0; // true`